# How to test a webapi controller xunit that requires authentication and authorization?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, controller, jwt

I have a custom authorize attribute.
I have tried using `TestServer` where `Startup` is another `Startup` class that I created using an inmemory EF database.

```
 testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
 httpCLient = testServer.CreateClient();
```

This is a sample method. If I try the method using postman, I get forbidden request.

```
[RoleAuthorize(arguments)]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var users = _userService.GetAll();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

When I try this:

```
var scope = testServer.Host.Services.CreateScope();
var userService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
var userController = new UsersController(userService);
userController.GetAll();
```

There is no Unauthorized response, and I can get the users.

And I get `NotFound` with:

```
var data = await httpCLient.GetAsync("users");
var result = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How can I test the authorization and authentication?

Comment: You could refer to: [test API which is protected using JWT Bearer token authorization](https://damienbod.com/2019/07/07/system-testing-asp-net-core-apis-using-xunit/)